# This code show error. Could you teach me what is the error is and how to change it?

Tags: c

ERRRO CODE (advancedpower function)

When I operate this code and write the input, the output is wrong.

use : ln(x), e^x

consider when a == 0
x can be positive, negative, or zero or any fractional number
if a==0 ->  a^x=0

```
a^x=advancedpower(ln(exp(power(a^x)))
```

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <assert.h> 
int factorial(int x) 
{  
  if(x>0) 
  { 
    return (x*factorial(x-1)); 
    } 
    if(x==0) 
    {
    return 1; 
    } 
    else 
    return 0; 
}
float power(float x, float y) 
{ 
  float r; 
  r=1.0; 
  if (x==0) 
  { 
    return 0; 
    } 
    if (y==0&& x!=0) { 
    return 1; 
    } 
    else 
    for(int i=1; i<=y;i++) { 
    r=r*x;
    } 
    return r; 
} 

float exp(float x){ 
  float sum=1.0; 
  for (int i = 0;i<10; i++) { 
  sum = sum + (power(x,i)/factorial(i)); 
  } 
  return sum; 
} 

float ln(float x)
{ 
assert(x > 0); 
float o= 1.0; 
    for (int i = 1;; i++) { 
    int k = 2*i-1; 
    float t = 2.0* power((x-1)/(x+1),k)/k; 
    o=o+t; 
    } 
    return o; 
} 

float advancedpower(float n1,float n2){ 
    if (n1 ==0){
    return 0; 
    } 
    else 
    return (exp(power(n1,n2))); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
  float a, x; 
  scanf("%f%f", &a, &x); 
  printf("%.4f", advancedpower(a, x)); 
  return 0; 
}
```

input 2.0 0.5
output 1.4142

however when I enter 2.0 0.5, the output is 3.7183

What should I have to change.....

Comment: Why do you declare n and i in factorial if you don't use them at all?

Comment: By getting exp function, first time I've used it.

Comment: `power` takes arguments `x` and `y`, declares locals `a` and `b`, doesn't initialize them and uses them instead of the arguments.  Also, please indent your code correctly!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the input “2.0 0.5”, `a` is set to 2, and `x` is set to .5. Then `advancedpower` is called with arguments 2 and .5. In turn, `advanceddpower` calls `power`, also with arguments 2 and .5.

`power` is a recursive function. When `x` and `y` are not zero, it calls `power(x, y - 1)`. This results in calling `power` with arguments 2 and −.5. Then it executes the same code again, which calls `power` with arguments 2 and −1.5.  Then again with 2 and −2.5. This continues until the stack is exhausted, and the program crashes.

This code has not been written to handle these values. You need to rethink the design.

Comment: Show you mean that I should re design power function? How about other functions?